# drying a block using proc in Ruby 2.2

Tags: ruby

I have a piece of code that I would like to DRY up:

```rb
def start
  queue1.pop_all do |record|
    # some non-trivial logic
  end
  queue2.subscribe_one do |record|
    # the same set of non-trivial logic
  end
end
```

One way I have come up is to create a private method that returns a `proc`:

```rb
def start
  queue1.pop_all(&sync)
  queue2.subscribe_one(&sync)
end

private

def sync
  return proc do |record|
    # some non-trivial logic
  end
end
```

Is this a reasonable way to do this? Or are there better, more clear ways to organize code?

Comment: Too broad, possibly a fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: notice that your solution creates a new proc object each time the method is called. you could have used a class constant as well: `SOME_PROC = Proc.new do ... end` and saved on memory.

Comment: Can that logic become a method of record?

Comment: @WayneConrad unfortunately no.  The logic relies on `queue1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, your solution looks fine. Alternatives include:

Call a common method from your blocks:

```
def start
  queue1.pop_all{ |record| sync(record) }
  queue2.subscribe_one{ |record| sync(record) }
end
```

In your example, you emit a proc from method which has the down side of recreating the proc every time you call the method. To fix this, you could make your common proc a variable, not the result of a method call:

```
def start
  sync = lambda{|record| /* non-trivial stuff */ }

  queue1.pop_all(&sync)
  queue2.subscribe_one(&sync)
end
```

Comment: This is a great answer. It would be better if you pointed out that his original solution creates a new proc object each time the method is called. He could have used a static constant as well `SOME_PROC = Proc.new do ... end`

Comment: Thanks, edited. I considered the Constant as well, but for some reason that didn't feel right to me. I can't make a great argument why not, I just felt dirty when I started typing it...